# Different C++ mangled names in Boost library and in application

Tags: c++, clang, boost-filesystem, hpx

I am compiling HPX (a high performance computing library) in macos and it uses Boost. I am using clang 10 with meson as the build system. Using nm to dump the library and the application binary to inspect the symbols, I found that there is a one letter difference between them. The application that I am building, as the beginning of my learning path, is the HPX hello world example in the official documentation.

In `libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib` the symbol is
`__ZN5boost10filesystem6detail28directory_iterator_constructERNS0_18directory_iteratorERKNS0_4pathEjPNS_6system10error_codeE`

and in the application it is
`__ZN5boost10filesystem6detail28directory_iterator_constructERNS0_18directory_iteratorERKNS0_4pathEPNS_6system10error_codeE`

The only difference is a `j` character added after the `path` part of the mangled name in `libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib`. Why does this happen and what can I do about it? It is beyond my knowledge and any help will be profoundly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to the excellent https://demangler.com/, the first of these demangles to:

> _boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator_construct(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator&, boost::filesystem::path const&, unsigned int, boost::system::error_code*)

and the second to:

> _boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator_construct(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)

And you can now see that the difference is an extra `unsigned int` parameter in the first version.  *Why* that should be I don't know, but maybe that gives you some clue as to what is going on.

Comment: I suspect that the difference is caused by having two different versions of Boost. Boost 1.72 added the `unsigned int` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you guys. I was able to see that the symbols indeed refer to two different constructors for `directory_iterator` with the help of `c++filt`. I then inspected the HPX source code and found the only two places in one source file where the iterator is instantiated. I changed the code adding a `boost::system::error_code` variable to the constructor and it is now working perfectly. Since the new `unsigned int` parameter is the middle parameter, adding the error code variable to the constructor disambiguated it. This is how it is used now:

```
boost::system::error_code dir_ec;
for (fs::directory_iterator dir(libs_path, dir_ec); dir != notier; ++dir) {...}
```

I will open a pull request at the GitHub's project. It is a very nice library for HPC.